# in-place bool AND and OR in c++?

Tags: c++, boolean, operators, in-place

Is there something like in-place AND and OR operators for bools in c++, along this line?

```
bool someOk=false;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  someOk||=funcReturningBoolOnSuccess(i);
}
```

(I know I can write `someOk=someOk||funcReturningBoolOnSuccess(i)`, but it is not as pretty).

Comment: Are you looking for |=

Comment: No, `|=` is bit-wise.

Comment: @eudoxos: unless you need the short circuit capabilities, |= works the same. And there is no ||= or equivalent. If you need it often, you can however write your own little function that does it.

Comment: not the answer, but for the purpose similar to the example you can try std::any_of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer will be short: no, the C++ syntax does not allow such structure.

You have to use:

```
something = something || something_else;
```

<s>However.... if your function returns bool on success (as in, true on success)... Why don't you just use the following?</s>

```
someOk = funcReturningBoolOnSuccess(i);
```

Will it not return false on failure anyway? Seems illogical.

Why don't you just do:

```
bool someOk=false;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  if (funcReturningBoolOnSuccess(i)) {
      someOk = true;
      break;
  }
}
```

A lot more efficient :)

Comment: So why don't you just `break` after it is true?

Comment: I suppose the cycle should be terminated as soon as the function returned `true` - there is no need to check the rest values.

Comment: Is the crossed-out portion integral to this answer? If not, then just delete it. The edit history will keep a copy of it if anyone really needs to see it. If it's important to keep it visible, could you explain in words what's wrong with it instead of just crossing it out? The meaning isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the return is `bool`, you can use `|=` for this purpose (unless you strictly want to avoid calling `funcReturningBoolOnSuccess(i);` after the first success - in which case you have to use some `if` and `break` or change the condition of the `for` loop).

If the result is not `bool` value, then you probably need to convert it to that, since `|=` is indeed a bitwise operation. Any basic type in C or C++ can be converted to a `bool` by the simple trick of `!!` ("bang-bang" or "not-not") - it makes a `true` of anything non-zero and `false` of a zero result, which is what we want.

Comment: My guess is that the representation of `bool` is implementation-defined, so using `|=` may not work in general?

Comment: I don't see why that would cause a problem. `true` and `false` should still be two constant values (and they can be converted to an integer according to section 4.5 in the standard), no matter what the actual binary bit-pattern happens to be. Although I'm not aware of any implementation that has `true` as something other than 1, it may be 3, 6 or 42 in some architecture, I suppose.

Comment: The promotion of `bool` to `int` is well defined: true becomes 1. That's independent of any bit pattern used to represent the value internally.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not in-place, but it's easier to use.

```
void OR(bool& x,bool y)
{
   x = x || y;
}

/* later on */

bool someOk = false;

// someOk = false
// funcRetBoolOnSuc(8) = false
OR(someOk,funcRetBoolOnSuc(8));
// someOk = false

// someOk = false
// funcRetBoolOnSuc(8) = true
OR(someOk,funcRetBoolOnSuc(9));
// someOk = true
```

Or, because bool accepts only 0,1 as values you could do this:

```
someOk |= funcRetBoolOnSuc(x);
```

Comment: Note that neither the function nor the `|=` operator exhibit the short-circuiting behavior we would expect from the hypothetical `||=` operator; `funcRetBoolOnSuccess` will always be called, even when `someOk` is already true.